# (Beamer) Navigation bar with Sections and SUBsections but without SUBSUBsections?

Tags: beamer, navigation, themes

How do you produce a navigation bar containing the sections and subsection but excluding the subsubsections? I'm using `PaloAlto` theme.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the beamer templates `subsubsection in sidebar` and `subsubsection in sidebar shaded` so that they don't insert the subsubsection title:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{PaloAlto}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{subsubsection in sidebar}
  {\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}
\setbeamertemplate{subsubsection in sidebar shaded}
  {\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{test section one}
\begin{frame}test\end{frame}
\subsection{test subsection one}
\begin{frame}test\end{frame}
\subsubsection{test subsubsection one}
\begin{frame}test\end{frame}
\subsubsection{test subsubsection teo}
\begin{frame}test\end{frame}
\section{test section two}
\begin{frame}test\end{frame}
\subsection{test subsection two}
\begin{frame}test\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Here's the first frame of the resulting document, showing the sidebar without the subsubsection titles:

[image]